# C++: Is value initialisation apply recursively?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the below codes:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X { 
public:
    //X() {}
    int getX() const { return this -> x; }
private:
    int x; // <-- Tag 3
};

class Y { 
public:
    //Y() {}
    int getX() const { return this -> x.getX(); }
private:
    X x; // <-- Tag 2 value or default initialisation?
};

int main() {
    X x{};
    cout << x.getX() << endl;

    Y y{}; // <-- Tag 1 - value initialisation
    cout << y.getX() << endl;
}
```

Results:

```
0
0
```

Question:

1. Is Tag 2 value or default initialisation?
2. If Tag 2 is value initialised then Tag 3 be 0 since Class X will use the synthesized ctor. This seems to be the case since it produce 0.

Also on another note, the compilation shows data members are all initialised.

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wuninitialized -O2 -pedantic-errors -o a.o a.cc
$
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: @RemyLebeau But it's producing 0s.

Comment: It's POD data - it will get the value of whatever happens to be sitting in that area of memory already. If it's already 0, it will be 0. But if it's 42, it will be 42.

Comment: What precludes 0 from the set of indeterminate values? The answer is nothing. A 0 can be a result of vacuous initialization just like -453456.

Comment: That's what i understand as well. But the compiler clearly shows all data members are initialised. See my edit above.

Comment: Your edit doesn't demonstrate that. A compiler emitting a program and it having a certain behavior does not preclude undefined behavior of a construct.

Comment: Yes .. the 0 could be returned by accident. However as i said .. the compiler shows all data members are actually initialised. So that contradict the line of thought of what we expect.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica That's what i understand from the usage of -Wuninitialized. It is to detect and warn any uninitialised data members based on the construct of the code.

Comment: So, it's lack of a pedantic error means it's initialized?  You could run it in Visual Studio, put breakpoint on the value, and see if it ever gets written.  I've had probs. trying it in MinGW.  At best, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: It's a common extension apparently [*"All known compilers performs additional zero-initialization if a non-deleted defaulted default constructor is selected."*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). Guess it's easier to implement, and it's not like 0 is verboten here, the value is already indeterminate. Still, it's not standard mandated.

Comment: *"Is Tag 2 value or default initialisation?"* -- neither. "Tag 2" marks the definition of a data member; initialization occurs in the constructor. (There is some grey here, though, since an initializer could be specified here.) A better phrasing would be "Is `Y::x` value initialized or default initalized?" (At which point, you would no longer need the "Tag 2" label, although a comment on that line to draw attention to it might still be helpful.)

Comment: @JaMiT That's what i am trying to determine. Is Y::x value or default initialised? You're saying neither which makes me even more confused. :OP

Comment: @yapkm01 *"You're saying neither which makes me even more confused."* -- no, I am saying that the line `X x;` is not initialization, similar to how the line `cout << x.getX() << endl;` is not initialization. You are trying to determine how `Y::x` is initialized in your specific example, but that is not what you asked. You came close, but your wording is off.

Answer (score 2):

`Y y{}` is performing [*value-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) on `y`.

- Prior to C++11, that will perform *value-initialization* on `Y::x`, which will in turn perform *value-initialization* on `X::x`, setting it to 0.
- From C++11 onward, that will perform [*zero-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) on `Y::x`, which will in turn perform *zero-initiaization* on `X::x`, setting it to 0.

From cppreference.com's documentation on [value-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization):

> The effects of value initialization are:
>
> |  |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1) if T is a class type with at least one user-provided constructor of any kind, the [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) is called; 2) **if T is a non-union class type without any user-provided constructors, every non-static data member and base-class component of T is value-initialized**; | (until C++11) |
> | 1) if T is a class type with no [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) or with a user-provided or deleted [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor), the object is [default-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization); 2) **if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization)** and then it is [default-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) if it has a non-trivial default constructor; however, all known compilers come into case (2) when a non-deleted defaulted default constructor is selected by [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), even if there is a user-provided default constructor, see Notes; | (since C++11) |
>
> 3. if T is an array type, each element of the array is value-initialized;
> 4. otherwise, the object is [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

Comment: So the value initialisation applied to Y also apply to X as well, right? So it is recursively applied.

Comment: You are compiling for C++11, in which `X::x` would end up zero-initialized, not value-initialized. But yes, there is a bit of recursive logic from parent object to child members, though in this case the compiler is likely to optimize it since the types in question are trivial.

Comment: i just find it hard to understand those clause. Can you give me examples of clause 1) & 2) for "since C++11"?

Comment: @yapkm01 your own classes are examples of clause 2. "*if T is a class type [X and Y are] with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor) [you commented out your default constructors, so the compiler implicitly generate its own], the object is zero-initialized and then it is default-initialized if it has a non-trivial default constructor [Y's constructor may not be trivial since it has to call X's constructot, but X's constructor is trivial]*"